# Displaying HTML from a Database by using MVC 3 (ASPX ViewModel)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm using MVC 3 (the ASPX ViewModel) while I store and display data from my SQL database. I've tried using the raw input to store it as well as using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode. Neither are working when I try to display. I've tried using the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode as well as using `<%: Model.MyHtmlVariable %>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: "not working" is generally a bad description for a problem.  You should post some code because all 3 of your attempted techniques should display something on that page.

Comment: I would think it would be obvious enought that I'm not getting HTML. The title does say displaying HTML from a database.

Comment: Well it wasn't obvious to me.  At first glance this reads like MyHtmlVariable simply isn't populated.  Just think of how clearer "is outputting encoded HTML" is vs "not working".

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the constructive criticism. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the traditional "<%= html %>" syntax should render it out for you but may not depending on what you're doing.  If not, try to wrap it in an HtmlString object, like so:

<%= new HtmlString(html) %>

MVC should respect that and render it out properly.

If you're just looking to display the encoded HTML, the "<%: html %>" syntax is your friend

Comment: Thanks Jess! Also, someone had pointed out to use a method that resturns an IHtmlString to keep consistency of the inline code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div to target and set the html using an jquery/javascript call to the controller action.

```
jQuery.get("/Controller/Action", 
     function(response) {  
          $("#MyDiv").html(response) 
     });
```

See if something like that works.